# SSJS Activities: Create Folder path

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, dataextensions, ssjs, folder

I am writing to know how can I do several actions on a Data Extension and Create Folder using Javascript by SSJS

Currently I can not create a folder.
I do not understand what is the problem .
By the way the only tool in Marketing Cloud that tells me if the script is successful is the "Automation" that I created specifically which tells me if the script is "Completed" or gives "Error".

Definitely something wrong in the JavaScript code. However I ask you to assist me at least to create a sub-folder under the folder "Data Extensions". Can you tell me if this code is correct or not?

```
<script runat=server>

Platform.Load("core","1");

var myDE = Folder.Retrieve({Property:"Name",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"Data Extensions"});
myDE.SetID(12345);

var newFolder = {
    "Name" : "Folder Script",
    "CustomerKey" : "test_folder_key",
    "Description" : "Test added",
    "ContentType" : "dataextension",
    "IsActive" : "true",
    "IsEditable" : "true",
    "AllowChildren" : "false",
    "ParentFolderID" : 12345
};

var status = myDE.Add(newFolder);

</script>
```

Regards
Riccardo Pruner

Comment: /*  <script runat=server>

Platform.Load("core","1");

var myDE = Folder.Retrieve({Property:"Name",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"Data Extensions"});
myDE.SetID(12345);

var newFolder = {
    "Name" : "Folder Script",
    "CustomerKey" : "test_folder_key",
    "Description" : "Test added",
    "ContentType" : "dataextension",
    "IsActive" : "true",
    "IsEditable" : "true",
    "AllowChildren" : "false",
    "ParentFolderID" : 123456
};

var status = myDE.Add(newFolder);

</script> */

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you require `Parent Folder ID` to create the folder path and same need to pass in `ParentFolderID` DataFolder object properties.

You can hard code your DataExtension Folder ID OR you can get dynamically by using `SSJS` link below:

```
<script runat=server>

Platform.Load("core","1");

var myDE = Folder.Retrieve({Property:"ContentType",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"dataextension"});
var myDEParentFolderID = myDE[0].ID;

var newFolder = {
    "Name" : "Folder Script",
    "CustomerKey" : "Folder Script",
    "Description" : "Test added",
    "ContentType" : "dataextension",
    "IsActive" : "true",
    "IsEditable" : "true",
    "AllowChildren" : "false",
    "ParentFolderID" : myDEParentFolderID
};

var status = Folder.Add(newFolder);
Write(status);

</script>
```

**Result:**
OK

Comment: Dear Palash, 
 thanks a lot for your answer. I understand what you told me. 
So I just tried to run the script that you wrote but again doesn't work. I see that the line " var myDEParentFolderID = myDE[0].ID; " gives an Error. What do you think ?

Comment: I am wrong !!!! I forgot an ">" when I close the javascript code. 
Great Palash ... Great!!!

Comment: So Now I can create a Folder path as I wish.
I can also create Data Extensions as I wish.
Finally I'd want move these DE in the folder requested.....how can I do this ?

Comment: Do you want to move DE using SSJS OR Manually ?

Comment: Yes, using SSJS!

Comment: I tried to do another script : 

<script runat=server>

Platform.Load("core","1");

var FolderScript= Folder.Retrieve({Property:"Name",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"Folder Script"});
var FolderScriptID = FolderScript[0].ID;

var DEscript= DataExtension.Init("ScriptDE20");
DEscript.setFolderId(FolderScriptID);

</script>

Comment: Ask new question and mentioned what you're trying to achieve with your script.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the advice. 
I'd like to create this folder path. I attach a img to show a sample path that I would want to create. Then I try to write a sample code where I create a Father Folder e the first Child Folder. 
Unfortunatly this code doen't work. Any suggestionss ?

[image]

```
<script runat=server>

Platform.Load("core","1");

var DE = Folder.Retrieve({Property:"Name",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"My Emails"});
var DEParentFolderID = DE[0].ID;

var folderONE = {
    "Name" : "2016",
    "CustomerKey" : "folder_script",
    "Description" : "forlderPath",
    "ContentType" : "email",
    "IsActive" : "true",
    "IsEditable" : "true",
    "AllowChildren" : "false",
    "ParentFolderID" : DEParentFolderID
};

var status = Folder.Add(folderONE);
Write(status);

var myDE = Folder.Retrieve({Property:"Name",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"2016"});
var myDEParentFolderID = myDE[0].ID;

var folderTWO = {
    "Name" : "Commerciali",
    "CustomerKey" : "folder_script1",
    "Description" : "forlderPath",
    "ContentType" : "email",
    "IsActive" : "true",
    "IsEditable" : "true",
    "AllowChildren" : "false",
    "ParentFolderID" : myDEParentFolderID
};

var status = Folder.Add(folderTWO);
Write(status);

</script>
```