# Trying to lookup Folder ID when there are multiple folders sharing the same name (SFMC WSProxy)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, wsproxy

I have this scenario right now where I'm coding a cloud page form with SSJS right now (I'm a bit of a noob at this) and the basic functionality is:

-Create data extensions automatically when form submitted (I get this part), and then automatically place data extensions in their respective folders- the folders would be dynamic according to their month:

So the folder structure would look like this
-Subscription Name
-Year
-Month
So it would look something like this: Subscription_1>2021>June

I was originally thinking I could leverage wsproxy to lookup by name, but it seems if I've got duplicate folder names (i.e. June is going to be a folder name in every Subscription Folder for this month) there isn't a way to specifically point at a folder path so that I could get that folder id- does anyone know if it's possible?

The other way I was thinking would be a bit more labour intensive and not as automated, but pre-creating the folders for the year, grabbing those IDs manually and hard-coding it into the SSJS based on the month + year- we've got 10 lines of business though- I'd prefer that I didn't have to do this 120 times.

Answer (score 2):

I would not consider that full answer, since the whole answer would require quite a bit of effort. Yet, here is the idea of how you can proceed:

1. You are already dynamically creating a Data Extension
2. Create dynamically folder path based on the ParentFolderID
3. Retrieve CategoryID (=FolderID) via API call done with SSJS, then parse the response body for the needed ID
4. Use parsed ID to move new Data Extension into it

As a reference you can use those sources:

[SSJS Activities: Create Folder path](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139595/ssjs-activities-create-folder-path)

[How to get category (folder) Id of SSJS activities](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/335556/how-to-get-category-folder-id-of-ssjs-activities)

[SSJS Activities : Move Data Extentions in a Folder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139763/ssjs-activities-move-data-extentions-in-a-folder)